# IPython: get return status from subprocess

Tags: ipython

I am using IPythons `getoutput()` to run a process in background. Which is nice as it does not open a separate window on my machine (I'm using the IPython shell inside Spyder IDE).

Is there a way capture the return status from the subprocess ?

Comment: If you can use IPython's system escapes, e.g. `!ls`, the return code is stored as `_exit_code` (in IPython 0.11, at least). This doesn't happen with getoutput, though.

Comment: I had a look at IPythons code. It just uses some parameters from subprocess.Popen which I was not aware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the subprocess module: http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html
Specifically, take a look at popen().

Comment: I knew that module. The problem is that these methods open a new window if I use them from the IPython shell in Spyder.

Comment: I don't really have experience with either IPython or Spyder. Sorry.